# If Router and Network Device Infected, Can Modem Be Too?

Tags: router

If my Verizon Fios router and other devices on my home network are infected with malware, could that malware infect the modem too?

I'm at least assuming it's the modem.  My router has a black cable running from it to a white box in my garage that was installed by Verizon when I ordered Fios.  I'm not very tech literate, but would that box be called the modem?

If so, could IT be infected by malware (that presumably got transferred to it from my router?

EDIT:  I've previously asked about malware on routers, but this is specific to modems.  I've tried Google searching malware on modems, but couldn't find anything.  Instead, I saw malware + routers in those searches.  So, that's why I'm asking this separate question.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I can say this: we are not a malware removal forum, and I'm not seeing evidence of you doing your own research on your questions.

Comment: @schroeder I apologize.  I had been getting some good answers from previous posts and figured it wouldn't hurt to ask a few more q's to unsure I'm doing what's best.  But, if it's not a malware removal forum, I'll rephrase my questions or not post them going forward!  I do appreciate everyone's help in the past and respect your guidelines!

schroeder, I did Google search modem malware, but couldn't find anything on it and that's why I posted the question.  I keep seeing router malware, but nothing related to modems.